# How to run my Intent if file exists

Tags: android

I want to run my Intent if the file exists, otherwise show a message that the file is not found. This is my code

```
if (!file.exists())

 {
  Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, " the file not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }      

 {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BooksActivity.class );
  startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: it is not working my app stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot an else statement and I modified your intent a little:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
  Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, " the file not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}      

else {
  Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,BooksActivity.class );
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: `MyActivity.this` is their "current"

Comment: very very thanks it's working thaaaaaanks